# How do I make List of Lists? And then add to each List values?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
class ExtractLinks
{
    WebClient contents = new WebClient();
    string cont;

    List<string> links = new List<string>();
    List<string> FilteredLinks = new List<string>();
    List<string> Respones = new List<string>();
    List<List<string>> Threads = new List<List<string>>();

    public void Links(string FileName)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(FileName);

        foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
        {
            HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];

            if (att.Value.StartsWith("http://rotter.net/forum/scoops1"))
            {
                links.Add(att.Value);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
        {
            int f = links[i].IndexOf("#");
            string test = links[i].Substring(0, f);
            FilteredLinks.Add(test);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < FilteredLinks.Count; i++)
        {
            contents.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
            cont = contents.DownloadString(FilteredLinks[i]);
            GetResponsers(cont);
        }
    }

    private void GetResponsers(string contents)
    {
        int f = 0;
        int startPos = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            string firstTag = "<FONT CLASS='text16b'>";
            string lastTag = "&n";

            f = contents.IndexOf(firstTag, startPos);
            if (f == -1)
            {
                break;
            }

            int g = contents.IndexOf(lastTag, f);
            startPos = g + lastTag.Length;
            string responser = contents.Substring(f + firstTag.Length, g - f - firstTag.Length);

            foreach (List<string> subList in Threads)
            {                
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

I created this variable :

```
List<List<string>> Threads = new List<List<string>>();
```

The first thing I don't know yet how to do is how to create inside Threads number of Lists according to the `FilteredLinks.Count` inside the Links method.

Second thing is in the  GetResponsers method I did:

```
foreach (List<string> subList in Threads)
{
}
```

But what I want is that first time it will add all the values from variable responser to the first List in Threads. Then when it's getting to the break; it stop then and then in the Links methods its calling `GetResponsers(cont)`; again this time I want that all the values in responser to be added to the second List in Threads.

I know that each time it's getting to the break; it will get the next `FilteredLink` from FilteredLinks.

1. How do I create number of Lists in Threads according to the `FilteredLinks.Count`?
2. How do I make the code in GetResponsers to add the responser ?

Comment: I would suggest you to simplify your question, so you can attract / motivate more people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need to specify the count for the number of lists in Threads, since it is a list, you can simply keep adding lists to it. So the first part is correct where you are declaring it.
2. The second part --> Your calling method will change. Look below for the calling method.
3. The third part --> Change private void GetResponsers(string contents) to private void GetResponsers(List threadList, string contents). Look below for implementation change.

Also the loop will look like this then

```
        //other code you have    
        List<List<string>> Threads = new List<List<string>>();

        public void Links(string FileName)
        {

      // ...other code you have
       for (int i = 0; i < FilteredLinks.Count; i++)
            {  
               threads.Add(new List<string>);
                contents.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
                cont = contents.DownloadString(FilteredLinks[i]);
                GetResponsers(threads[threads.Count - 1], cont);
            }
        }

     private void GetResponsers(List<string> threadList, string contents)
                {
                    int f = 0;
                    int startPos = 0;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        string firstTag = "<FONT CLASS='text16b'>";
                        string lastTag = "&n";
                        f = contents.IndexOf(firstTag, startPos);
                        if (f == -1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        int g = contents.IndexOf(lastTag, f);
                        startPos = g + lastTag.Length;
                        string responser = contents.Substring(f + firstTag.Length, g - f - firstTag.Length);
                        threadList.Add(responser);    
                    }   
                }
```

PS: Please excuse the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i make List of Lists ? And then add to each List values?

The following codesnippet demonstrates you, how to handle `List<List<string>>`.

```
List<List<string>> threads = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
list1.Add("List1_1");
list1.Add("List1_2")
threads.Add(list1);

List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
list1.Add("List2_1");
list1.Add("List2_2")
list1.Add("List2_3")
threads.Add(list2);
```

> 1. How do i create number of Lists in Threads according to the
>      FilteredLinks.Count ?

```
for(int i = 0; i < FilteredLinks.Count; i++)
{
  var newList = new List<string>();
  newList.Add("item1"); //add whatever you wish, here.
  newList.Add("item2");
  Threads.Add(newList);
}
```

I'm afraid I can't help you with Question #2, since I don't understand what you try to achieve there exactly.